# Work out the amount of hours in last week

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, pdo

I currently have a table of clocking logs which references two other tables. One table it references contains a log of clocking in's and the other a record of clocking out's: each has a unique ID.

For example (for each `rwh_clock_in` and `rwh_clock_out` table):

```
id 1
atTime 2018-06-05 14:01:38
userid 1
```

Then inside the clocking log (`rwh_clocking`):

```
id 1
clockInId 1
clockOutId 1
hours 8
```

I am trying to use the last tuesday `strtotime('last tuesday')` and the next tuesday `strtotime('next tuesday')` to work out the hours that employer has done during that week.

I am using `PDO::Prepare()`, the dates are placed in during the `<` `>` and then the user ID is placed in for which user I am calculating the hours during the most recent week for.

So far I have this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM rwh_clocking 
WHERE ( CASE WHEN cio.ci > ? 
        AND cio.co < ? ) 
        FROM ( SELECT ? AS id, 
             ( SELECT atTime FROM rwh_clock_in WHERE userid = id ) AS 'ci',
             ( SELECT atTime FROM rwh_clock_out WHERE userid = id ) AS 'co' ) cio;
```

However, this throws me an error in the `CASE`. Any help would be appreciated.

My desired output would be:

```
id clockInId clockOutId hours
1  1         1          8
2  2         2          4
etc..
```

When the clock_in and clock_out `atTime` is between last tuesday and next tuesday.

I have also tried:

```
SELECT clock.*, ( CASE WHEN cio.ci > ? AND cio.co < ? )
FROM rwh_clocking clock, ( SELECT ? AS 'id', 
    ( SELECT atTime FROM rwh_clock_in WHERE userid = id ) AS 'ci',
    ( SELECT atTime FROM rwh_clock_out WHERE userid = id ) AS 'co' ) cio;
```

I receive an SQL error: **subquery returns more than 1 row** when I run this:

```
SELECT c.clockInId, c.clockOutId, c.hours, cio.*
FROM rwh_clocking c,
    ( SELECT 1 as 'id',
        ( SELECT atTime FROM rwh_clock_in WHERE atTime > NOW() ) AS 'ci',
        ( SELECT atTime FROM rwh_clock_out WHERE atTime < NOW() ) AS 'co' ) cio;
```

So I believe that I need to cycle through each subquery before doing a `CASE`. Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

```
SELECT c.clockInId, c.clockOutId, c.hours
FROM rwh_clocking c,
    ( SELECT 1 as 'id',
        ( SELECT atTime FROM rwh_clock_in WHERE atTime > NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE AND userid = id ) AS 'ci',
        ( SELECT atTime FROM rwh_clock_out WHERE atTime < NOW() AND userid = id ) AS 'co' ) cio;
```

Now returns me all the data but the times are not being taken into consideration.

*UPDATE:**

This now brings back no rows when they do exists.

```
SELECT c.clockInId, c.clockOutId, c.hours
FROM rwh_clocking c,
    ( SELECT 2 as 'id',
        ( SELECT id FROM rwh_clock_in WHERE atTime > NOW() - INTERVAL 60 MINUTE AND userid = id ) AS 'ci',
        ( SELECT id FROM rwh_clock_out WHERE atTime > NOW() + INTERVAL 5 MINUTE AND userid = id ) AS 'co' ) cio
WHERE c.clockInId = cio.ci AND c.clockOutId = cio.co
```

Comment: Please see [why should I provide an MCVE for a simple query](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need all those CASE expression and sub-queries. Use two joins (uses three named parameters `userid`, `timein` and `timeout`):

```
SELECT c.*
FROM
    rwh_clocking AS c
INNER JOIN rwh_clock_in AS ci
    ON c.clockInId = ci.id AND ci.userid = :userid
INNER JOIN rwh_clock_out AS co
    ON c.clockOutId = co.id AND co.userid = :userid
WHERE ci.atTime > :timein AND co.atTime < :timeout
```

[Live fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7e7bee/12)

Comment: Thankyou so much! I think I was getting confused trying to build subqueries. +1 for the explanation as well!